# Named Pipe Provider Error code 40

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have literally tried everything, from enabling named pipe to adding exception to ports in the firewall, to everything possible in surface configuration. I can connect to the SQL instance(using TCP and Named Pipes) with SQL Server Management Studio. But `sqlcmd` throws an error:

```
Login timeout expired
```

Help!

Comment: you might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec

Comment: is port 1433 open?

Comment: you need more detail in your question.  Please add the sqlcmd command line you used, along with how you are connecting in SSMS.  Something is clearly different about how you are specifying the server name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give us a lot of detail, but this article covers most of the basics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190181(v=sql.105).aspx